# Partition by with conditions

Tags: sql-server

I have a table which contains info on customer purchases per year and month respectively. Here is a simplified version.

| id | year | month | nb_purch |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2001 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2001 | 2 | 4 |
| 1 | 2001 | 3 | 7 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 1 | 2001 | 12 | 3 |
| 1 | 2003 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 2003 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 2003 | 3 | 5 |
| 1 | 2003 | 4 | 7 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 1 | 2003 | 12 | 3 |
| 2 | 2001 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2001 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 2001 | 3 | 5 |
| 2 | 2001 | 4 | 7 |

Basically there are several constraints. The database contains only the years when the client has made a purchase. If the client has made a purchase within the year X then X will be divided into 12 rows according to months. The months with no purchases have the value 0.

What I am trying to do is to retrieve the number of purchases per certain "windows". Currently its value sits at 3 years. For example i want to retrieve the sum of nb_purch within the last 3 years starting from 2003 march. This means i need to add all values from
march 2001 to march 2003.

```
  SELECT SUM(nb_purch) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY year, month ASC ROWS BETWEEN 36 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS LAST_3_YEARS FROM T
```

The issue i am facing here is that the table does not contain all years and therefore in my example of purchases between (2001 and 2003) if the year 2002 is missing then i am getting false results. I would like to avoid having to add all missing years and fill them with NULL values for each customer.

Comment: You could do a dummy table of all months in all years and left join to your table to fill in the gaps. Alternatively choose a more appropriate way of getting the last 3 years than assuming there will be 36 rows

Comment: Look at [calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6844/sql-server-calendar-table-example/) - a useful addition to any database if you need to work with date ranges.

Comment: A Calendar table is the way to go. You *could* do with with a triangular join too, though I'm not sure how performant such a solution would be.

Comment: This feel very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72609018/tsql-query-to-get-sum-of-last-3-months-qty/72609184), which has several answers on how to achieve what you are after.